# SVN created repository - cannot import

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I'm running Visual SVN server.  I created a repository.  I see my repository in this directory, C:\Repositories.  I also installed tortoise SVN, so now how do I upload a project to source control?

#### Attempt 1

```
Import C:\dev\apache-ofbiz-09.04 to https://smallville/svn
Repository moved permanently to 'https://smallville/'; please relocate
```

#### Attempt 2

```
Command: Import C:\dev\apache-ofbiz-09.04 to https://smallville  
Error: OPTIONS of 'https://smallville': 200 OK (https://smallville)
```

#### Attempt 3 & 4

```
tried with localhost, same errors
```

---

edit: i was using the wrong URL -- they look like this

```
https://localhost/svn/projectName
```

you can get it if you navigate to the target repository, right click, copy URL to clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try clicking on the hyperlink in the VisualSVN manager? It should open a web browser to the page. If it does not, try adding `Repositories` to the URL (or whatever the name of the directory your repositories are stored in).

---

- Right-click on your project folder
- Select the TortoiseSVN submenu and click Import
- Enter your SVN server (you can find the URL in the VisualSVN manager)
- Enter additional optional information
- Click OK

It should import the folder to the repository. Congratulations, you’ve just begun version-controlling your source!

- Make some changes
- Observe the TortoiseSVN overlays on the folder and files
- Right-click your project folder
- Select the TortoiseSVN submenu and click commit
- View the changes (double-click specific items to diff them)
- Add an update comment
- Click OK

Congratulations, you’ve just updated your project. You can also revert or browser using either the TortoiseSVN repository browser, or your web-browser by going to the same URL.